# Referencing default layout from refs.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Classic setup for different layout for different device size:

Requirements:

- Handset/7" tablet - Single pane
- 10" Tablet - Dual pane

Layouts are:

- `layout/main.xml` - single pane layout
- `layout/main-dual.xml` - dual pane layout

And having following for 10" in `values-large/refs.xml` works perfectly:

```
<item name="main" type="layout">@layout/main-dual</item>
```

However having this for 7" in `values-sw600dp/refs.xml` does not:

```
<item name="main" type="layout">@layout/main</item>
```

I suppose this is because I reference main layout to itself. Referencing a copy of `main.xml` with different name works as supposed.

Not having `refs.xml` at all in `values-sw600dp` produces dual pane layout.

Exception in `onCreate()`:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0e0000 type #0x1 is not valid
03-14 18:36:45.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)
03-14 18:36:45.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
```

So my question is how to reference default layout from `values-xxx/refs.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

You can directly make the layout in res folder.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Comment: Your solution will work and I'm aware of it, however the idea to minimize duplicate layouts..

Comment: Means you want to reuse same layout..?

Comment: Check the all layout first from layout-sw600dp folder. So if you test suppose layout-sw600dp/test.xml is same looking for the layout-sw720dp these layout so dont make the layout in layout-sw720dp/test.xml... It will looks same we dont need to repeat that layout. right..?

Comment: Yes it means to reuse same layout. In the question stated that I want to use main.xml for handsets and 7", main_dual.xml for 10" and not having 10 copies of main.xml. Refs.xml are for that to my understanding

Comment: I dont know about that I only know that from developer site If you want to make the different layout looking different so you need to create the main also for the 10' tablet. caz its having the different resolution and different sizes of screen. And put the same name of XML in both folder. means main.xml for 7' folder and main.xml in 10' folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it was where I had my ref.xml files placed.

For my large & sw600dp related files, I placed them correctly in the `.../res/values-large` and `.../res/values-sw600dp` folder.  However, I placed the default `.../res/layout` folder instead of the `.../res/values` folder.    After moving it to the correct directory, things worked as expected.

In android studio, you can combo box at the upper left and select `Android` and it will just show the android related resources/files.  When I had it wrong, the first `refs.xml` showed up under layout and the other two showed up under `values/refs.xml`.  I did have a picture of this to post, but my reputation points are not yet high enough.